# Type boolean is not assignable to type "team" in Filter function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a list of football teams fetched from an API and also a state that selecting the team so I can apply some styles on a selected team. So far it's working pretty well but I wanted to get the team name like this;

```
interface team {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  icon: string;
}

const MainPage: React.FC = () => {
  const [teams, setTeams] = useState<team[]>([]);

  const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = useState<number>();

  const selectedTeam = teams.filter((team): team => team.id === isSelected);
```

So `isSelected` state is not a boolean value, I know naming like this was wrong. But it's an ID, it's working fine but I wanted to filter the teams array and get the selected team's details, just to get its name. But I see this error;

[image]

I don't understand this, doesn't filter function expects a boolean value? what does that have to do with team type? can someone explain to me?

- I tried to make the type "any" it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how TS expects you to write that line:

```
  const selectedTeam = teams.filter((team): boolean => team.id === isSelected);
```

Writing `(team): team` implies that that the lambda you are passing to the `filter` will return a `team` but `filter` expects a function returning a `boolean`. You don't have to explicitly say that the `filter` will return a team because that's already implied by its own signature.

Comment: ah my mistake, so by writing like that I implied that return will be "team" type. I understood, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You explicitly specify the return of the filter as `team`, which confuses typescript, either remove it or replace with boolean. Change this

```
 teams.filter((team): team => team.id === isSelected);
```

to

```
 teams.filter((team): boolean => team.id === isSelected);
```